# Spring4D TDistinctIterator<string>.ToArray() not working?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I want to use the Spring4D `TDistinctIterator` to get the distinct `Values` in a `TDictionary`. Therefore I have the following code:

```
var
  d: TDictionary<Integer, String>;
  v: Vector<String>;
begin
  d := TDictionary<Integer, String>.Create();
  d.Add(1, 'test');
  d.Add(2, 'test');
  d.Add(3, 'test');

  v := TDistinctIterator<string>.Create(d.Values, nil).ToArray();
end;
```

However, this gives an access violation in the `ToArray`. Is this a bug or should I use the iterator in another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that you are using the implementing classes rather then an interface based approach. It's important to realise that much of the spring4d code is intended to be used via interfaces and you typically should not refer to the implementing classes behind those interfaces.

What is happening in your case is that `TDistinctIterator<T>` has lifetime managed by reference counting. Your code does not handle that lifetime management correctly, and the `TDistinctIterator<String>` instance is destroyed before you call `ToArray`, leading to the access violation.

As well as the problem with `TDistinctIterator<T>`, your code also doesn't handle the lifetime of the dictionary correctly.

Your code should look like this:

```
var
  d: IDictionary<Integer, String>;
  v: Vector<String>;
begin
  d := TCollections.CreateDictionary<Integer, String>();
  d.Add(1, 'test');
  d.Add(2, 'test');
  d.Add(3, 'test');

  v := TEnumerable.Distinct<String>(d.Values).ToArray();
end;
```

Note also that when written this way you can remove `Spring.Collections.Dictionaries` and `Spring.Collections.Extensions` from your uses list. The only two units you need are `Spring` and `Spring.Collections`.